# Armstrong Number python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, numbers

Que: Print the first Armstrong number in the range of 1042000 to 702648265 and exit the loop as soon as you encounter the first Armstrong number.
Use while loop

this is my code :

```py
upper = 702648265
lowers=1042000
for num in range (lower, upper + 1):
    o= len (str(num))
    sum = 0
    temp = num
    while temp > 0:
        x = temp % 10
        sum += x ** o
        temp //= 10

    if num == sum:
        print(num)
        break
```

Output:

```
1741725
```

I got 1741725 answers in my output. but when I check Armstrong's number in mathematically its wrong answer. I want to correct my code mathematically so tell me my mistake?

Comment: What the heck is an armstrong number?

Comment: Why `x**o`? you need the cube of the digit. Just do: `sum(int(d)**3 for d in str(num))`

Comment: Please provide the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  "Address my mistake" is not a problem specification.  As best I can see, the main problem is that you've done nothing to look for the problem, yourself.  Insert some strategic `print` statements to trace the data and control flow.  Follow the computations with a hand simulation: do the arithmetic yourself.  Find where the program differs from your hand calculations.  *Then* you may have a Stack Overflow question.

Comment: See this lovely reference for [debugging help](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs).

Comment: The solution for you is already available on the internet. Did you try to review your code against this [Armstrong. Number code](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/examples/armstrong-number)

Comment: A positive integer is called an Armstrong number of order `n` if `abcd... = a**n + b**n + c**n + d**n + ...`

Comment: btw your range starts with `lower` instead of `lowers`. Also dont use `upper` as it is a python module. Try to use `u` and `l` instead

Comment: @Joe Ferndz: hey I did not want to check number is  Armstrong number or not. I want a Specific number list of  Armstrong number in a given interval

Comment: Most of your posted code specifically checks whether a given number is an Armstrong number.  Why do you reject the link @JoeFerndz gave you?

Comment: @MyLife, i checked your code. Are you sure the answer that python and your computer is giving is incorrect? See my answer below. I did the calculation manually and it is correct. Not sure what you are checking. Can you look at your calculations again pls.

Comment: @MyLife, if the answer is correct, upvote the answer and close the question. For your reference, read about what to do when someone [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) your question.

Comment: @JoeFerndz: I don't think that 'l' is great name. One letter names generally are not descriptive and according to the book of Life, the Universe and Everything (a.k.a. PEP8): "Names to avoid. Never use the characters 'l' (lowercase letter el), 'O' (uppercase letter oh), or 'I' (uppercase letter eye) as single character variable names. In some fonts, these characters are indistinguishable from the numerals one and zero. When tempted to use 'l', use 'L' instead."

Comment: @AivarPaalberg, thank you. Makes sense and will keep this in mind when I create variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is correct. Your code however needs to be corrected a bit.

Your code:

```
upper = 702648265
lowers=1042000
for num in range (lower, upper + 1):
```

Corrected code:

```
upper = 702648265
lowers=1042000
for num in range (lowers, upper + 1): #it should be lowers instead of lower
```

Here o is 7. So you have to calculate to power of 7 on each number

```
1 ^ 7 + 7 ^ 7 + 4 ^ 7 + 1 ^ 7 + 7 ^ 7 + 2 ^ 7 + 5 ^ 7

= 1 + 823543 + 16384 + 1 + 823543 + 128 + 78125

= 1741725
```

So the answer is correct.